# visual studio 2015 can't connect to p4v, getting "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, p4v

System preferences: windows server 2012, visual studio 2015, p4v.
My system booted yesterday (probably windows update).
Since then, when I open visual studio 2015 IDE and try to connect to an existing workspace I used to connect before, I'm getting p4vs error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: We are seeing this as well just starting today. Windows 10. VS 2015.

Comment: Related forum post http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/3956-object-reference-not-set-error-during-solution-load/page__hl__extension#entry20882

Answer (score 3):

This is a P4VS bug, and starts to appear since the plugin is updated automatically.
It seems the bug was introduced on the last version.
In order to overcome it [just install the previous version of P4Vs](http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/3956-object-reference-not-set-error-during-solution-load/#entry20891):

- Uninstall P4VS 2016.2
- Close Visual Studio
- Download ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/bin.ntx86/p4vs11.vsix
- Double click on the p4vs11.vsix to install P4VS 2016.1
- In order to avoid the automatic update of this extension, open Visual Studio --> Tools --> "Extenstions and Updates" find P4VS extension and uncheck "Automatically update this extension"

Answer (score 0):

It was related to the VS <-> P4V adapter which was probably updated and needed to be removed and re-install